# how to set java web application's context root when working with reverse proxy

Tags: java, apache, reverse-proxy, contextroot

1. My old way using mod_jk in apache and configure virtual host in tomcat
   In the JSP file, I refer to CSS as below

   /`<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/styles.css`

while the home link is set to

```
/<%=request.getContextPath()%>/
```

so this worked fine when I use mod_jk in apache to work with tomcat using ajp;

1. When I try to configure reverse proxy as below

ProxyPass / http://localhost:800/mywebapp

ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:800/mywebapp

the home page can be retrieved fine but the css request becomes
http://mydomain.com/mywebapp/mywebapp/css/style.css
so the css file can not be retrieved correctly;

1. I think one possible way is to always use relative path like ./style.css or ../style.css
   a. since header/footer are shared, and the home page is in a different level with detail page, it's inconvenient to use relative path because they're at a different level
   b. still, I think the home link will have to be /<%=request.getContextPath()%>/

so I wonder what's the way to set contextroot fine in java web and also work fine with reverse proxy?

thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

As I know your application server (Tomcat) isn't able to be aware of a reverse proxy presence. Generally speaking, it can be contacted through any number of reverse proxies or directly by browsers. A network configuration is usually used to limit this, not HTTP or Java.

So, you must accurately rely on relative URLs to make your application work well.

When I have to deal with reverse proxy presence (almost always due to SSO architectures), I embed a "junction" configuration string item (the portion of the URL used in the proxy to map the application) and use it in the only places where I need to build an absolute URL.

Comment: hi, thx for reply; questions: 1. how do you specify your links to css and home link? 2. how do you specify reverse proxy setting in apache config? thx.

Comment: I usually add an Helper class with a static method that returns me a config param, that I put in a .properties file, so the reference to you css could be: <%=UrlHelper.getBasePath()%>/css/styles.css and in the getBasePath method you can read properties, environment, db, and so on.

Comment: do  you set this in  your reverse proxy config?  ProxyPass / http://localhost:800/mywebapp,